# How to: Text field only accept certain words

Tags: php, javascript, forms

How to set up text field that only accept certain words?
I have about 150 words that are allowed.
Words are ticker symbols as these: ZLTU, ZTLAD, ZMASD...

Comment: You may use `autocomplete` of jQuery.

Comment: Is using select box an option?

Comment: Have you considered an ordinary `<select>`-dropdown?

Comment: Select box or select dropdown do not meet my needs, But thanks for try!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// You could create an object and validate that 
// the input string is in the object:
var tik={
    A:"Agilent Technologies",
    AAPL:"Apple Inc.",
    BAC:"Bank of America",
    'BRK.A':"Berkshire Hathaway (class A shares)",
    C:"Citigroup Inc.",
    CPRT:"Copart",
    GOOG:"Google",
    HNZ:"H.J. Heinz Company",
    HOG:"Harley-Davidson Inc.",
    HPQ:"Hewlett-Packard",
    INTC:"Intel",
    KO:"Coca-Cola Company",
    MMM:"3M Company",
    MSFT:"Microsoft",
    TGT:"Target Corporation",
    TXN:"Texas Instruments",
    WMT:"Wal-Mart",
    WAG:"Walgreens"
}
function validTicket(inp){
    return inp.value in tik
    //returns true or false
}
function stockCo(inp){
    return tik[inp.value];
    //returns company name or undefined
}

//examples
var input={value:'HNZ'};

//alert(validTicket(input)+'\n'+stockCo(input))


// Or list them all in a delimited string and look for indexOf.
// Remember to enclose the first and last items with your delimeter.
function validTick(inp){
    var tik= '|A|AAPL|BAC|BRK.A|C|CPRT|GOOG|HNZ|HOG|HPQ|INTC|KO|MMM|MSFT|TGT|TXN|WMT|WAG|';
    return tik.indexOf('|'+inp.value+'|')!= -1;
}
// alert(validTick(input))
```

Answer (score 2):

The new HTML5 form elements can deal with what you need, but there is still the issue of backward compatibility.

Basically you can test the value of an input field by listening to the `onblur` event and correct, remove value, or alert the user if the value is not in the set. Alternatively, you can just use the `<select>` element to "force" the user to select from a fixed set of values.